# How to calculate the sum of geometric series

Tags: java, geometric-mean

I want to calculate the sum of a geometric series. ie: 1 , 5 , 25 , 125 , etc
I try to use the math formula to calculate it: a(r^n -1)/(r-1)

My code:

```
int a = 1;
int r = 5;
int deno = r -1;
int n = 3
int rn = r^n -1 ;

int total = a * rn / deno;
```

Apparently there is wrong with the code and only some values like the example I give works. I do not know why QAQ

I think the problem is the symbol `^`
can anyone explain what `^` does in java? Appreciate it

Comment: show an example which doesn't work. Paste expected and evaluated result.

Comment: Can you show the actual output of the code, and the desired output?

Comment: In Java, you do not use `^` for power of numbers. It's actually the exclusive or operator.

Comment: @papaya the code I put on does not work. It is expected to print out 125, but it really prints out 6. I wonder why it resulted in this number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atleast in Java 7, the symbol ^ does not mean power.

Try this, you would also like to put a condition where r>1 or r<1. Both have different formuals.

```
        int a = 1;
        int r = 5;
        int deno = r -1;
        int n = 3;
        double sum=a*(Math.pow(r, n)-1)/deno;
```

Comment: so I need to use `Math.power(x, y)` instead of `^`. Ok got it.